# What is the equivalent of HttpServiceHost in ASP.NET WebAPI?

Tags: c#, wcf-web-api, asp.net-web-api

I wanted to try out [this](http://www.bizcoder.com/index.php/2011/04/16/the-worlds-simplest-wcf-web-api/) example of a self-hosted webservice (originally written in WCF WebApi), but using the new ASP.NET WebAPI (which is the descendant of WCF WebApi).

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Http;

namespace SampleApi {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            var host = new HttpServiceHost(typeof (ApiService), "http://localhost:9000");
            host.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Browse to http://localhost:9000");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }

    [ServiceContract]
    public class ApiService {    
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "")]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetHome() {
            return new HttpResponseMessage() {
                Content = new StringContent("Welcome Home", Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain")
            };    
        }
    }    
}
```

However, either I haven't NuGotten the right package, or HttpServiceHost is AWOL. (I chose the 'self hosting' variant).

What am I missing?

Comment: [This](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASPNET-Web-API-Self-Host-30abca12/view/Reviews) has helped me to get something working, but it doesn't look like a strict equivalent.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please refer to this article for self-hosting:

[Self-Host a Web API (C#)](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/self-host-a-web-api)

The complete rewritten code for your example would be as follows:

```
class Program {

    static void Main(string[] args) {

        var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration("http://localhost:9000");

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "API Default", "api/{controller}/{id}", 
            new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        using (HttpSelfHostServer server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config)) {

            server.OpenAsync().Wait();

            Console.WriteLine("Browse to http://localhost:9000/api/service");
            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to quit.");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
}

public class ServiceController : ApiController {    

    public HttpResponseMessage GetHome() {

        return new HttpResponseMessage() {

            Content = new StringContent("Welcome Home", Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain")
        };    
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.